# Есть слово преодобренный?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Предодобренный (кредит) или преодобренный? Какой вариант правильный?

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?tbm=bks&hl=ru&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В рамках русского словообразования корректно: **предодобренный** (**пред**варительно одобренный кредит, проект и т. п.). *Русская* приставка **пре-** в значении предварительности *не* употребляется и может лишь в ряде случаев выступать сокращенным вариантом приставки **пере-** в словах с другим значением (превышенный, преодолённый, преосвященство). То, что жаргонизм "*преодобренный*" (он встречается реже нормального слова) имеет-таки хождение, можно объяснить подражанием английскому слову **pre-approved**, которое попадается на глаза неискушенным в языках (тем более, в принципах перевода) банковским служащим. В результате к *русскому* корню приделывается иноязычная приставка, по аналогии с полностью заимствованными словами "презумпция", "префикс" и т. п. Даже если слово *преодобренный* найдется в каком-то списке новых терминов, такое  словообразование *некорректно*.

Есть ещё слово **переодобренный**, с другим значением: *повторно, заново одобренный* (в изменившихся условиях или на новый срок).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***предодобренный***.

**Пояснение**

1) В русском языке значительное количество слов иноязычного происхождения имеет **латинскую приставку PRAE со значением «перед»**:

преамбула – предисловие, вводная часть конституции или соглашения      .

превалировать – дословно – преобладать, превышать, быть впереди

презентация – представление чего-то нового, презентабельный - представительный

президент – сидящий впереди (для сравнения: председатель)

прелюдия – вступление к пьесе (перед пьесой)

препарат – приготовленный перед опытом

прецедент, беспрецедентный – первый случай перед другими, идущий впереди.

префикс  – морфема, стоящая впереди

2) А вот интересное слово с русской основой: ***препозиция*** – положение перед другим

3) Но *препозиция* – это исключение. Дело в том, что у русской приставки ПРЕ и так уже есть два разных значения (значение ПЕРЕ и  превосходная степень), в третьем значении (перед) мы ее просто не узнаем.